# Question about proof on isomorphism theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

> Let $U$ and $W$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$. Prove that the **quotient spaces** $$(U+W)/U \ \ \text{and}\ \ W/(U\cap W)$$ are isomorphic.

Proof :
The map
$$
\alpha\colon W\to (U+W)/U
\qquad
\alpha(x)=x+U
$$
is a linear map. Its kernel is $U\cap W$ and therefore we get an isomorphism
$$
(U+W)/U\cong W/\ker\alpha=W/(U\cap W)
$$
by the first isomorphism theorem.

I have two questions:

1. I understand that the kernel is $U\cap W$ but how do we show that it is only $U\cap W$?
2. Why does this mapping $\alpha(x)=x+U$ cover the whole space of $(U+W)/U$? (The question mentioned about coset but i thought coset only applied to multiplication not addition of x+U here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If $w\in\ker\alpha(\subset W)$, $\alpha(w)=0+U$, with means that $w\in U$. But then $w\in W\cap U$.
2. If $x\in(U+W)/U$, then $x=v+U$ for some $v\in U+W$. So, $v=u+w$, for some $U\in U$ and some $w\in W$. Since $u\in U$, $v+U=(u+w)+U=w+U$. But then $x=\alpha(w)$.

Comment: thank you sir, are these two points considered trivial btw--that is why the proof did not include them?

Comment: I suppose so, but I can't speak for the author.

Comment: thank you got it; for 2. its trivial but i think you meant $+=(+)+U=w+U$.

Comment: And sorry but just another quick question: do we have to prove double containment for 2. or just $ \alpha(w) \subset (U+W)/U)$? If we only have to prove one direction, how is that a homomorphism/linear mapping?

Comment: What I did proves that $\alpha(W)\supset(U+W)/U$. Since it is trivial that $\alpha(W)\subset(U+W)/U$, this proves that $\alpha(W)=(U+W)/U$.

Comment: got it, so then does that help us show the map we established is in fact a group homomorphism? i am a bit confused as to what the operation for the group homomorphism here is or how to show it is a group homomorphism (apologies but i am a bit new to this and still confused about some of the definitions)

Comment: It's a linear isomorphism, since it is both a bijection and a linear map.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

For your first question, a double containment proof should work. That is:

Can you show $U \cap W \subseteq \text{Ker}(\alpha)$ (this shouldn't be hard, and from the sounds of your question, you may have already done it.)

Next is $\text{Ker}(\alpha) \subseteq U \cap W$. Since $\text{Ker}(\alpha) \subseteq W$ already (after all, $\alpha$ is defined on $W$), it suffices to show that $\text{Ker}(\alpha) \subseteq U$. I suggest taking some $v \not \in U$ and showing that $\alpha(v) \neq 0 + U$.

---

For your second question, let $v + U \in (U+W)/U$. That is, $v \in U+W$, and we are taking its $U$-coset.

We know what vectors $v \in U+W$ look like, though: $v = v_w + v_u$ with $v_w \in W$ and $v_u \in U$. Do you see how to use this to show that $\alpha$ is surjective?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: so is coset not just multiplication only but can also be addition? i am a bit confused about the definition of coset here

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: the definition is " the left cosets of H in G are the sets obtained by multiplying each element of H by a fixed element g of G (where g is the left factor)" but here we used w+U which is adding each element of U to w, not multiplying, so is coset a different definition here?

Comment: When we say "multiply" we really mean "use the group operation". Since the group operation in vector spaces is written $+$, we write the coset as $v+U$ instead of $vU$. The notation is different, but the concept is the same.

Comment: got it thank you, and i am actually having a bit trouble showing ∩⊆Ker(), say if $v\in U\cap W$, then $\alpha (v) \in U$, so \alpha (v) would not be contained in the codomain and why would that make v in the kernel? (does not being in codomain automatically make it 0?)

Comment: If $v \in U \cap W$, then $\alpha(v) = v + U$. But $v \in U$, so $v + U = U = 0 + U$.

Comment: i am sorry but im new to this so i am confused to what kernel is here really, i thought kernel means whatever maps to 0 but here kernel seems to mean anything that $\alpha(v)$ maps to U, so it maps to a set U, not a zero vector.